# Copying Embedded H2 database data to another registry instance

Tags: wso2

I have a local Gov. registry 4.6.0 setup with standard out of box H2 embedded database where I added lots of artifact types and data to each custom artifact type.

I want to copy all data from my local H2 database to another Gov. registry 4.6.0 instance which is running on a server.

I do not want to repeat this on the registry instance running on the server and have to recreate the custom artifact types and have to re add the data that I have locally.

I could not find any documentation that allows me to do that.

Is there any way to do this?

Also how can I connect to and browse the embedded H2 database? Is there some script to run?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that it's not recommended to use H2 DB for governance registry, and config registry DB instances in production. It's ok to use as the local registry DB though. All the user modified artifacts will be in either governance or config registry.

Comment: yes I realize that. Since we are a large global corporation of over 50K employees in 120 locations at the moment we are trying to create a demo of the registry with artifacts and data to get management buy in which is why not using any production databases like Oracle, DB2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two options,

1. H2 database can be found at /repository/database  directory. You can simply copy this directory in to other server and replace it.   To do that,  1st stop both  server, then copy the directory and replace it with other server's directory. Then restart both.
2. Registry check-in  check-out client.  More detail are in [docs](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Check-in+Client)

You can connect to H2 database and browser it. In this [blog](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-browse-h2-database-of-wso2.html), It has been explained. You can go through it.

Comment: Option 1 sounds simpler. I assume you need to reboot the registry server even if we choose option 2. Correct?

Comment: If I create a dump using the following url https://localhost:9443/registry/ instead of https://localhost:9443/registry/somepath to some collection, will this copy the full local registry db to the dump file?

Comment: Not sure why but both options did not work for me as yet. I copied all the files in option 1 but do not see any change in the server registry artifacts list or any data in my local registry.

Comment: 2nd option server is stopped and error shown  
checkin-client.bat co https://localhost:9443/carbon/
-u admin -p admin -f C:\Apps\wso2greg-4.6.0\remote.dump
Using CARBON_HOME:   C:\Apps\WSO2GR~1.0\bin\..
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
Error in initializing the Realm Service. Some databases like h2, derby in file mode, doesn't allow to have multiple connections. In such case, Please make sure no other is connected to the database. If you running the script in separate place, please make sure you have given absolute paths to the file-based database urls.

Comment: Both options do not work for me. i tried option 1 twice and restarted the server and option 2 multiple times and get the errors for option 2 as above

Comment: Very sorry. Option 1 now works. I was copying files to the wrong drive. Option 2 still does not work. Maybe my machine is messed up causing option 2 issues. Not sure...

Comment: Yes... Option 1 should work...It is the simple way. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [Check-in client](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Check-in+Client) that is shipped with WSO2 GReg. You can use the the Check-in client to take a dump of the registry (with -f option), and then check-in that dump to the new registry db.